# Text substitution failure with CURL while creating a remote repo in Git Bash

Tags: curl, github, directory, repository, git-bash

I encountered a problem using CURL in git bash:

I intended to create a remote repository using the name of the directory.

However, `$folder` did not work properly in the script below and the repository the code generated is *username/-folder*.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
folder=`basename "$PWD"`
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'First commit'
curl -u 'username:password' https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"$folder"}'
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/$folder.git
git push -u origin master
```

Please replace only username and password in line 6 and line 7 to reproduce the problem.

> ```
> $ ./script
> Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/username/../directoryname/foldername/.git/
> [master (root-commit) 20725a2] First commit
>  Committer: username
> Your name and email address were configured automatically based
> on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
> You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly. Run the
> following command and follow the instructions in your editor to edit
> your configuration file:
>
>     git config --global --edit
>
> After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
>
>     git commit --amend --reset-author
>
>  5 files changed, 33 insertions(+)
>  create mode 100644 code/bash.txt
>  create mode 100644 code/fraud.bat
>
> ... A BUNCH OF MESSAGES HERE THAT SO THOUGHT WAS SPAM...
>
>   "milestones_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/username/-folder/milestones{/number}",
>   "notifications_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/username/-folder/notifications{?since,all,par100 5329  100  5311  100    18   3433     11  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 3444ipating}",
>   "labels_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/username/-folder/labels{/name}",
>   "releases_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/username/-folder/releases{/id}",
>   "deployments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/username/-folder/deployments",
>   "created_at": "2018-06-20T14:14:07Z",
>   "updated_at": "2018-06-20T14:14:07Z",>       "ssh_url": "git@github.com:username/-folder.git",
>   "clone_url": "https://github.com/username/-folder.git",
>   "svn_url": "https://github.com/username/-folder",
>   "allow_squash_merge": true,
>   "allow_merge_commit": true,
>   "pushed_at": "2018-06-20T14:14:08Z",
>   "git_url": "git://github.com/username/-folder.git",
>   "allow_rebase_merge": true,
>   "network_count": 0,
>   "subscribers_count": 0
> }
>
> remote: Repository not found.
> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/example1.git/' not found
> ```

Comment: The problem can be resolved by escaping the quotation marks, `"{\"name\":\"$folder\"}"`

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be resolved by escaping the quotation marks
`"{\"name\":\"$folder\"}"`.

Comment: I'm glad that this turned out to be something simple. We were all probably distracted by the item that it was a problem with Git Bash or cURL. OP and future readers should note that there *are* some issues with running cURL in Git Bash (on Windows) to be aware of: https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/573